# uwsgi max number of processes and threads

Tags: python, multithreading, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I have a Flask API that allows users to download files, but if they run multiple wget/curl calls at the same time, they'll have to wait for the first job to finish before the next one starts.
I realized that uWSGI starts with a single process and a single thread by default. Is it common that I have to define the number of processes and threads in <my_app>.ini file (e.g. processes = 5, threads = 2) for my app, or there is a way to set it to unlimited number of processes (like the app can dynamically assign a new process to every request from a user who needs to download several files concurrently?)